# How to set ruble symbol with iText 7?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, itext7

I use iText 7.1.4 and often use Russian fonts in it. I want to set the ruble symbol in my PDF file, but I can't.

Here is the code snippet:

```
tableVariations.AddCell(priceSettings.HasLines ?
  new TextCell(
    $"{variation.Price}₽",
    PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(priceSettings.ContentFont, "Cp1251", true),
    priceSettings.ContentFontSize,
    priceSettings.ContentForegroundColor.ToDeviceRgb(),
    priceSettings.LinesColor.ToDeviceRgb(),
    priceSettings.LinesThickness,
    TextAlignment.RIGHT) :
  new TextCell(
    $"{variation.Price}₽",
    PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(priceSettings.ContentFont, "Cp1251", true),
    priceSettings.ContentFontSize,
    priceSettings.ContentForegroundColor.ToDeviceRgb(),
    TextAlignment.RIGHT));
```

where `tableVariations` is a `Table`. `priceSettings.ContentFont` is a Russian font.

I can see only the price in the result PDF file, but the `₽` symbol doesn't appear.

I tried like this:

```
new TextCell(
    $"{variation.Price}₽",
    PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(priceSettings.ContentFont, PdfEncodings.UNICODE_BIG, true));

new TextCell(
    $"{variation.Price}\u20BD",
    PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(priceSettings.ContentFont, PdfEncodings.UNICODE_BIG, true));

new TextCell(
    $"{variation.Price}\u20BD",
    PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(priceSettings.ContentFont, PdfEncodings.UTF8, true));

new TextCell(
    $"{variation.Price}₽",
    PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(priceSettings.ContentFont, PdfEncodings.UTF8, true));
```

I had't to get any result...

Comment: The font encoding must be unicode, not cp1251.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's follow the official iText7 sample (it's been written in Java, but since iText is autoported to C# from Java there should be no diffference): 
https://github.com/itext/i7js-examples/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/fonts/tutorial/F05_Russian_correct_encoding.java

Let's add the ruble symbol to the text and see that it will not be rendered well with FreeSans. The reason is that there is no ruble symbol inside the font, and FontForge proofs this hypothesis:

[image]

Now let's use the Arial font provided in windows. FontForge shows that the symbol is handled insided that font:

[image]

Now let's change the encoding to IDENTITY_H:

`PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FONT, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);`

and see that everything has been processed correctly:

[image]

So I suggest you to check your font. It looks like there is no ruble symbol inside it.